# Change style of element based on property of other element

Tags: html, css

I just learnt [[attribute=value]](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp) and it changes style of itself based on it's *own* attribute value.

If I want to change style of element based on *other* element's attribute value. Like if `href` of `a` is blank then `div` should be hidden.

Something like

```
a[href=""] then div
{
    display:none
}
```

Comment: It also depends on the position of `div` in your `HTML` code.

Comment: It would only work if `div` is child of `a`. If it's not child, than you can't do that

Comment: Unless the "other" element is a descendant, later-sibling or the descent of a later-sibling, of the element with the specific attribute then this is not possible. And without your HTML we can't say either way. So, please: show your "*[mcve]*" code so that we can help you, or advise you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with the `href` attribute too.

**example with inner `<div>`:**

```css
a[href=""] div {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <div>This is not visible!</div>
</a>
```

**example with following `<div>`:**

```css
a[href=""] + div {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="">This link should hide the following div!</a>
<div>This is not visible!</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but rather too simplified and with no explanation as to the caveats and problems inherent in the question.

Answer (score 0):

try with example

```css
.common {
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
   float:left;
}
a[href="#one"] + div {
    background:#000;
}
a[href="#two"] div {
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#one">one</a>
<div class="common"></div>
<a href="#two"><div class="common"></div></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a[href="#"] + div {
display: block;
}
a[href=""] + div{
 display: none;
}


<a href="#"></a>
<div></div>
```

The CSS will apply according to the href of a tag

Comment: The OP already understands this, it's referenced directly in the question.

Answer (score -1):

And if the `div` is not included in the `<a>`, you can do it this way:

```
a[href=""]:hover + div {
    display:none;
}
```

I think you meant this, because putting a block element like `div`, in an inline element like `a` is not XHTML verified.